# Cannot understand why eval is passed in as an argument, i.e., df.<COL_NAME>.apply(eval).apply(np.array) before further processing of the col

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I was going through this piece of code available on [OpenAI](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/Semantic_text_search_using_embeddings.ipynb). It is trying to read a CSV and create a dataframe. I checked that in the dataframe, there is already a column named `"babbage_search"`, which contains vectors. What I don't understand is why do we need to pass `eval` as an argument in this line of code:

```
df["babbage_search"] = df.babbage_search.apply(eval).apply(np.array)
```

If I remove `.apply(eval)`, I get an error:

```
ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U45750'), dtype('<U23')) -> None
```

This is the code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding, cosine_similarity

datafile_path = "../ReviewsWithEmbeddings.csv"  
df = pd.read_csv(datafile_path)
df["babbage_search"] = df.babbage_search.apply(eval).apply(np.array)

# search through the reviews for a specific product
def search_reviews(df, product_description, n=3, pprint=True):
    embedding = get_embedding(
        product_description,
        engine="text-search-babbage-query-001"
    )
    df["similarities"] = df.babbage_search.apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(x, embedding))
    print('SIMILARITIES:', df.similarities)
    res = (
        df.sort_values("similarities", ascending=False)
        .head(n)
        .combined.str.replace("Title: ", "")
        .str.replace("; Content:", ": ")
    )
    if pprint:
        for r in res:
            print(r[:200])
    return res


res = search_reviews(df, "Christmas gift", n=3)
```